# Why won't my video play in my UIView when using AVPlayer

Tags: ios, swift, avplayer

I am using the following code to play a video using AVplayer for some reason the video will not get played,
But the moment i change the video to be played in the main view the video plays fine I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong

The below code won't play the video

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    let videoView : UIView = {
        let video = UIView()
        return video
    }()
    
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        constraints()
    }
    
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        setupVideoPlayer()
    }
    
    func setupVideoPlayer()  {
        let videoToPlay = AVPlayer(url: URL(fileURLWithPath: Bundle.main.path(forResource: "coverr--08-20-surfing-waves-cloudy-08-3016", ofType: "mp4")! ))
        let layer = AVPlayerLayer(player: videoToPlay)
        layer.frame =  videoView.bounds
        videoView.layer.addSublayer(layer)
        videoToPlay.play()
    }
    
    
}

extension ViewController {
    
    func constraints() {
        view.backgroundColor = .white

        view.addSubview(videoView)
        videoView.anchor(top: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, left: view.leftAnchor, right: view.rightAnchor, height: 450)
    }
        
    
}
```

when I change the code from

```
layer.frame = videoView.bounds
videoView.layer.addSublayer(layer)
```

to

```
layer.frame = view.bounds
view.layer.addSublayer(layer)
```

it works any ideas what I'm doing wrong

Comment: I noticed that you are not calling the super implementation in `viewWillAppear(_:)` override. Maybe this leads to that issue.

Comment: yes call super.viewWillAppear as well as try calling setupVideoPlayer() method in viewDidAppear.

Comment: thanks for the feedback I have tried both and still the same result, don't understand why it won't play

Comment: just a update I have fixed the issue my function should of been in viewDidAppear not viewWillAppear

Answer (score 0):

From what you describe, it sounds like the subview is not picking up the constraints.
You can try:

```
let videoView : UIView = {

    let video = UIView()
    video.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return video
}()
```